# Open form within a form C#

Tags: c#, forms

I'm wondering, is it possible to open a form within a form in C#? I mean for example, in form 1, there's a link that says: "Open form 2", when a user clicks that link, "Form 2" will open in the same form. It's just like navigation through different forms.  I need some codes to get started. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can host a form in another control (ie. a `Panel`). Set the `TopLevel` property of the form `false` and set your host control `Content` to an instance of your `Form`.

Example code:

```
var childForm = new ChildForm() {TopLevel = false, Visible = true};
while (hostPanel.Controls.Count > 0) hostPanel.Controls[0].Dispose();
hostPanel.Controls.Add(childForm);
```

**Edit:**

I assuming you want to show a form inside another form (control).

Showing another form(in a new window) is as easy as invoking the `Show()` / `ShowDialog()` methods on an instance of it as [`@Marco`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/604015/marco) mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018513/open-form-within-a-form-c-sharp/8018524#8018524).

Comment: Never use Controls.Clear(), it permanently leaks controls and window handles.